# How to validate date when using `String` instead of a `Date` type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, types

In an Asp.net MVC app, I have inherited this problem (if it is a problem?) where one developer has used `String` for Date type.

In my model the property reads:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Registration Date")]
public string Registrationdate { get; set; }
```

The business requirement is that the field is **not** required, but if there is something in that fields then it must be a **valid** date.

How would you implement this requirement, *without changing the data type*?

Comment: Would probably do something along the lines of implementing a check using DateTime.TryParse in the setter method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It looks like you're](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant) using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. The best way to do this using this library would be to create a new attribute to validate date strings and apply it to the property. Here's some code for you to start with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
class DateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var dateString = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateString))
        {
            return true; // Not our problem
        }
        DateTime result;
        var success = DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out result);
        return success;
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to expand on this code depending on what kind of strings you're expecting from the client. Also, this won't give you any client-side validation.

Comment: +1: you are absolutely right that I am using DataAnnotations and was hoping for something similar to this type of solution. I am going to try this out this evening.

Answer (score 6):

```
public string Registrationdate { 
    get; 
    set {
        DateTime date;
        var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
        if (isDate) { 
            _registrationDate = value; 
        }
        else {
          // Throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this is not a bad approach. But how do I show this as a validation errors in a MVC app? +1

Answer (score 1):

(sort of) pseudocode:

```
if (Registrationdate is not empty)
{
    RegistrationDateTime = new DateTime(Registrationdate);

    if (RegistrationDateTime is not valid DateTime)
        fail validation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular expression? Data Annotations has a regex attribute. Now you'd have to fix on a format, say ISO (yyyy/mm/dd) which may not meet your requirements.

Another alternative may be to create your own annotation.

Yet another solution could to use a nullable datetime (DateTime?). I'm not sure how that would be handled though, so some trial and error would be needed. It does however only need the addition of one ? so could be relatively easy to try.

Simon